# Есть ли способ использовать HTML5 и JavaScript для изменения локальных файлов?

Tags: javascript, html5

Другими словами, когда вы открываете какую-либо веб-страницу, может ли приложение изменять файлы на  компьютере? Если да, пожалуйста, опишите, какие технологии / API можно использовать для этого?

Comment: Надеюсь, что нет. Файлы являются собственностью пользователя комьютера и доступа к ним извне быть не должно.

Comment: Ответ - нет. См. [старый вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33746680/web-application-access-users-file-system)

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka javascript и html5 не только в браузере могут работать.

Answer (score 1):

вам нужен [Electron](https://electron.atom.io/) или его аналоги

Comment: Описанная вами программа меняет файлы без ведома пользователя?

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka это фреймворк для разработки дестктопных программ. На нём можно написать программу. которая будет менять файлы без ведома пользователя.

Comment: Она сможет менять файлы человека, который просто зашел на страницу в Интернете?

Comment: Десктопная программа запускается владельцем компьютера. Если это происходит без его ведома, то это вирус. Все знаем, что вирусы существуют.

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka в вопросе нет ничего про "просто зашел на страницу в Интернете". Electron - это стандартная обертка для создания десктопных приложений на html / js. На его основе сделаны VSCode, Slack, Atom и еще куча десктопных приложений. Вирусы, "без его ведома" и прочее к этому никакого отношения не имеют.

Answer (score -1):

"JavaScript не может читать/записывать произвольные файлы на жесткий диск, копировать их или вызывать программы. Он не имеет прямого доступа к операционной системе.

Современные браузеры могут работать с файлами, но эта возможность ограничена специально выделенной директорией – «песочницей». Возможности по доступу к устройствам также прорабатываются в современных стандартах и частично доступны в некоторых браузерах."

[Что НЕ умеет JavaScript?](https://learn.javascript.ru/intro)

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html